# PDE: Find an explicit expression for the solution of the IVP by using Fourier Transform

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform

Find an explicit expression for the solution of the IVP:

$u_{t}+cu_{x}+u=0$

$u(0,x)=f(x)$

by using **Fourier Transform**

That's how I started but don't quite understand what to do after! Any help would be highly appreciated! Thank you
[image]

Comment: Solve the ode for $\hat{u} $, the take the inverse Fourier transform.

Comment: Using the hint from Jose27, from your last line (which should be $\hat{u}_{t} = -ic \xi \hat{u} \color{red}- \hat{u}$) $$\hat{u}_{t} = -(1 + ic \xi)\hat{u} \implies \hat{u} = A(\xi) e^{-(1 + ic \xi)t}$$ and applying initial condition $$u(x,0) = f(x) \implies \hat{u}(\xi, 0) = \hat{f}(\xi) = A(\xi)$$ hence $$u = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \hat{f}(\xi) e^{-(1 + ic \xi)t} e^{-i \xi x} d \xi$$ Rearranging the integrand should make it clear what the solution is.